# What's the correct way to rotate a UILabel 90 degrees?

Tags: swift, rotation

I'm attempting to rotate a UILabel 90 degrees within a UIView.

The following snippet is an attempt to write something in Swift that can do that:

```
  //  #define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(x) (x * M_PI/180.0)

    let angle:CGFloat = (90.0 * 3.14/180.0) as CGFloat
    let rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)

    self.dayLabel.transform(rotation)
```

I encountered couple compiler errors: 
1) Attempting to convert radians to an angle encountered a double --> float conversion problem and hence, had to use '3.14' vs 'M_Pi'.

2)  I got the following error when attempting to actually doing the transformation on UILabel:
[image]

What's the correct way to rotate a UILabel 90 degrees?

---

Okay... I got the transform syntax but...
Here's the original image:
[image]

My goal is to position 'TUE' vertically against the left side of the cell.

I originally tried a 90 deg counter rotation:

```
    self.dayLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90)
```

And got the following: 
[image]

I tried to vary the degrees but can't get a solid vertical position.

I do/can I have *tighter* control over the transformation?

Comment: Why use `transform` as a method and not assign it? Also, try using `CGFloat` constructor instead of casting to it.

Comment: use radians not degrees

Answer (score 72):

Below code works in Swift 3, 4 and 5:

```
dayLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2)
```

Comment: You can also use `.pi / 2.0` instead of `CGFloat(M_PI_2)` in Swift 3.

Comment: But still you need to make it as `CGFloat` since `.pi` is `Double`. Thanks!

Comment: You're right that `.pi` is a member of `Double`, but it's also a member of `CGFloat` and `Float`: `Float.pi, Double.pi, CGFloat.pi`

Comment: because of this my view frame update (x:0,y:0,width:300,height:300) to (-62.132 -62.132; 424.264 424.264)

Answer (score 21):

Try this way :

```
dayLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
self.dayLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2)
```

Is the correct way to perform the transformation of 90 degrees, where `M_PI_2` is the predefined radian value for 90 degrees.

Comment: Need to cast mpi2 to float like so `CGFloat(M_PI_2)`

Comment: because of this my view frame update (x:0,y:0,width:300,height:300) to (-62.132 -62.132; 424.264 424.264)

Comment: M_PI_2 is now deprecated, you can use .pi / 2 instead

Answer (score 8):

Swift 4 solution with degrees value:

```
let degrees : Double = -90; //the value in degrees
self.dayLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(degrees * .pi/180))
```

Answer (score 8):

> swift 4

```
@IBOutlet weak var ourView: UIView!

    ourView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double(-45) * .pi/180))
//i gave it -45 degree.
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to use `CGFloat.pi` here.

Answer (score 2):

`UIView.transform` is a `property` of the `UIView` not a `function`.
Try setting `self.label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)` instead.

For more information
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform

Answer (score 1):

To ease calculation between radians and degrees forth and back I would even suggest to use the measurement API, which offers such built in:

```
let measurement = Measurement<UnitAngle>(value: 90.0, unit: .degrees)
let angleInRadians = measurement.converted(to: .radians).value
label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angleInRadians)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dayLabel.transform = dayLabel.transform.rotated(by: .pi / 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func rotate(button: UIButton) {
let angles = [CGFloat(Double(270) * .pi/180),
              CGFloat(Double(180) * .pi/180),
              CGFloat(Double(90) * .pi/180),
              CGFloat(Double(0) * .pi/180)
]
for i in 0..<4 {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.125, delay: 0.125 * Double(i), animations: {
        button.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angles[i])
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score -8):

Apparently I have adjust down to the 1/100 of a counter degree to nudge it vertical:

```
self.dayLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-89.55)
```

The result: 
[image]

Comment: It is clear from the documentation that `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` gets an angle in radians as a parameter, you just happened to find an angle which looked quite similar to what you wanted.